# How can I get sum of value from a column based on condition mixed with second list using R?

Tags: r, dplyr

When I try to do operation on 2 lists I get a error messages and the calculation does not work properly.(see end of question)

```
list2 <- list2 %>% 
mutate(sum_of_part = sum(list1$part[(list1$id < list2$id) & (list1$id >= lag(list2$id))]))
```

So what I want to do is:
Get the sum of "part" of all rows in list1 where the "id" is between the "id" of the current row in list2 and the "id" of the row before.
I also want to count the number of rows which are used to calculate the column sum_of_parts.

list1

```
id    Part   ...
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      6
99     11
100    11
191    11
222    11
333    11
```

list2

```
id   ...
1
3
4
88
99
```

solution

```
id   ...  sum_of_parts    count
 1   ...        2           1   
 3   ...        9           3
 4   ...        10          2
88   ...        6           1
99   ...        11          1
```

But because my list2 is a lot smaller then my list1, I do get this errors(there are some more but they look almost the same):
In list1$id < list2$id :   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close, this one gets me all the time!

`mutate` operates by group I believe, so if you haven't specified a group it will try to use the whole column in a vectorised operation (which is usually more efficient), and thus the error about different lengths.

If you want to operate on each row, you can use `rowwise()`, to make the following calculations treat each row as a group. So `id` will be a length one vector in the `mutate` call.

Note we need to specify the lag before grouping, otherwise using the logic above, there will be no previous `id` in a length one vector.

```r
library(dplyr)

list1 <- readr::read_csv(
'id,part
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,6
99,11
100,11
191,11
222,11
333,11')

list2 <- readr::read_csv(
'id
 1
 3
 4
 88
 99'
)

list2 %>% 
  mutate(lag_id = lag(id, default = 0)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%  
  mutate(sum_of_part = sum(list1$part[(list1$id <= id) & (list1$id > lag_id)]),
         count = length(list1$part[(list1$id <= id) & (list1$id > lag_id)])) %>% 
  select(-lag_id)
#> Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>      id sum_of_part count
#>   <int>       <int> <int>
#> 1     1           2     1
#> 2     3           7     2
#> 3     4           6     1
#> 4    88           0     0
#> 5    99          11     1
```

Comment: you could use `rowwise` instead of specifying the group (key) explicitly and then grouping by it.

Comment: Great idea, much more readable and concise. This will save me so much unnecessary typing in future :)

Comment: Could have used list2$id-lag(list2$id) for count guess. Thank you for your answer. It works and it saved me :))